# миграция linux livecd на hdd (linux mint)

Tags: linux, миграция

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно, ли перенести файлы из загрузочного образа Linux на жесткий диск?
То-есть: загрузиться с загрузочного диска (livecd, liveusb) доустановить в него софт, разметить жесткий диск, и склонировать эту систему, в которой уже работем, что-бы получилась, такая, псевдо-ускоренная установка?

Потом, после перезагрузки, загрузится с hdd и уже на нем работать, как если-бы мы установили: сохранение настроек, доустановка софта, изминение локали...

Для примера, в Knoppix, рекоммендуют следующее:

```
knoppix tohd=/dev/hda1
```

> Knoppix will start from CD, copy itself to the specified device and then continue loading from there. You can then take the Knoppix CD out of the drive.

Правда, не знаю, будет-ли это установкой, миграцией, или еще чем-то?

Comment: в принципе, вы примерно описали процесс установки операционной системы. потому ответ — да, установить операционную систему на hdd — можно.

Comment: вы бы не могли подсказать как это сделать? то-есть какие папки скопировать, и как, что нужно добавить?

Comment: нажать на кнопку «установить». если кнопки не наблюдаете — смотрите документацию на сайте дистрибутива.

Comment: мне не надо нажимать кнопку "установить". скажем, если я уже загрузился, и установил нужный софт..., настроил, и тепер надо перенести настроенную систему на диск.

Comment: извините, ничего не понял. в вопросе речь, вроде бы, про live-cd, а в комментарии вы пишете: «установил нужный софт». куда вы его установили?

Comment: В чём проблема сделать `apt-get install` ещё раз на установленной системе и подсунуть ~/.config обычным копированием? Зачем извращаться с переносом ливсиди на винт?

Comment: Вам нужно кастомизировать live-cd под себя или просто установить систему на hd? Если последнее, то да, большинство live-cd содержит команду установки себя на hd, после чего можно работать как с обчноустановленным дистрибутивом. Если нужно live-cd с предустановленным софтом, это кастомизация.